# How can I group the x-variable in SAS with proc freq ? -- group categories using cross tabulate in SAS proc

Tags: sas, frequency, crosstab, proc, proc-sql

I would appreciate your help on this...

I have two columns and I want to get the count of months whether the type is 1 or 2, so I used proc freq:

```
proc freq DATA= count_types;
output out= counts;
TABLE amount_of_months * Type / nocum nopercent norows;
```

The proc freq returns a result like this:

```
Months           |     Type                         |Grant Total
-----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------
1                |count(type1)=41  | count(type2)=60| 101
2                |count(type1)=50  | count(type2)=20| 70
3                |count(type1)=60  | count(type2)=30| 90
4                |count(type1)=10  | count(type2)=40| 50
5                |count(type1)=45  | count(type2)=15| 60
...
```

The output table looks like this:

```
amount_of_months | Type (contains type1=t1 or type2=t2) |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                | t1                                   |  41 =count(type1) 
1                | t2                                   |  60 =count(type 2)
2                | t1                                   |  50 =count(type 1)
2                | t2                                   |  20 =count(type 2)
3                | t1                                   |  60 =count(type 1)
3                | t2                                   |  30 =count(type 2)
4                | t1                                   |  10 =count(type 1)
4                | t2                                   |  40 =count(type 2)
5                | t1                                   |  45 =count(type 1)
5                | t2                                   |  15 =count(type 2)
```

I want to get a proc freq that looks like this below...instead of having 1,2,3,4,5:

So I can get groups like this:

```
Months|           Type
---------------------+-------------------
<2    | count(type1) | count(type2)
2-4   | count(type1) | count(type2)
4>+   | count(type1) | count(type2)
---------------------+-------------------
```

Is it possible to make using proc freq directly or should I make a table with the 2 Types in two different columns?

I tried with proc format and when case but it didn't work...Does this problem come from the Type column?

Code tried

```
proc format; 
  value amount_of_months
    0-2 = '<2' 
    2-4 = '2-4'
    4-high = '4+'
  ;

proc freq data = count_types;
  tables amount_of_months * type / norow nocol nopct ;
  format amount_of_months amount_of_months. ;
run;
```

Comment: Format is the exact correct approach to use here. Show what you've tried with a format and how it didn't work.

Comment: An example of using a format (more complicated than your example) is here https://gist.github.com/statgeek/1c6f38ef368a4272cf458b017fc63d4b

Comment: You want to make a format to apply to the MONTH variable.  From what you showed you do not need to attach any special format to the TYPE varaible.

Comment: Here is the code I tried! Instead of counting the types it counts the months which is wrong...                                                                                 
 ```````                                                                                                                        
proc format;
value amount_of_months  0-2 = '<2'
      2-4 = '2-4'
      4-high = '4+';

proc freq data = count_types;
tables amount_of_months * type / norow  nocol nopct ;
 format amount_of_months amount_of_months. ;
run;   ````````````

Comment: @Student1212 What's wrong with the output from that? I ran that, with some test data, and it does what you want I think, other than perhaps having the 2 and 4 categorized wrong.  What do you want differently from that output?

Comment: The output should have a column with the months grouped a second column with the sums of type 1 a third column with the sums of type 2 and the last one with the total.with the code i made i get the counts of the month from each type not the summary of the types.